# Java: Using the index of a linkedList, how to change item for desired value

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to only change the int value of a specific item in a LinkedList, to a new int value. I would also like to understand the logic of how it is done, not only the code.

p.s I can not change anything, I can only add to the inside of the methods.

Thank you.

For example:
[Green tea, 1] to [Green tea, 2]

The method where this needs to happen

```
public void changeItemCount(int k, int m){

}
```

Class where the question is

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class GroceryList {


    //this class will create an object that contains a list of Grocery Items
    
    //variable
    private LinkedList<GroceryItem>   glist;  //holds GroceryItems
      
    
    //constructor: instantiates glist to an empty groceryList
        
    public  GroceryList()  {
         glist = new LinkedList<GroceryItem>();
        
    }       
    
    // return number of GroceryItems in glist
    public int getSize() {  
        return glist.size();
    }
    
    //return GroceryItem at requested index 
    public GroceryItem getItem(int k) {
        GroceryItem m = glist.get(k);
        return m;
    }
    
    //add GroceryItem  x to end of glist
    public void addItem(GroceryItem  x)  {  
        glist.add(x);
    } 
    
    //Remove item at index k from glist
    public GroceryItem  removeItem(int k )  {  
        return glist.remove(k);
    } 
    
    
    //change item count for k item in glist to m
    public void changeItemCount(int k, int m) {
        //need help here
    }
    
   
    //Should work as is
    public void sortList( ) {  
        glist.sort(null); 
        System.out.println("Sorted GroceryList: " + glist);
    }  


}
```

other class in relation:

```
public class GroceryItem implements Comparable<GroceryItem> {

    
    //this class will create items from a Grocery Store and the desired quantity
    
    //variables
     private String name;   //grocery item name
     private int count;     // number needed; make sure count is always >= 0
    
     
     //set count = 1; set name  = s in following constructor
     //if only a string is passed, default count is set to 1
     public GroceryItem ( String s) { 
         count = 1;
         name = s;
     } 
  
    //constructor
     // set name = s  and set count = initCount  in following constructor
     //if a string and an int are passed then we set them to the passed values
     public GroceryItem ( String s , int initCount) { 
         name = s;
         count = initCount;
     }  
    
     
     //returns the current count
     public int getCount() {  
         return count;
     }
     
     //returns a fixed/known amount 
     public void setCount(int m) {  
         count = m;
     }
     
     public String getName() {  
         return name;
     }

    //@Override
    public int compareTo(GroceryItem o) {
        
        if( name.compareTo(o.getName() ) < 0) //less than compared item
            return -1;
        else if (name.compareTo(o.getName()) > 0) //greater than compared item
            return 1;
         else
            return( count - o.count); //duplicated item?
    }

    //toString method: formatting: [bananas, 3]
    public String toString() { 
     
    name.toString();
    String temp = Integer.toString(count);
    String formatt =  name + ", " + temp ;
    return formatt;     
    }


}
```

main driver:

```
public class GroceryListDriver {

//this class tests the methods of the two other classes 
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        //creating 10 items in GroceryItem
        GroceryItem items1 = new GroceryItem("banana", 5);
        GroceryItem items2 = new GroceryItem("apples", 5);
        GroceryItem items3 = new GroceryItem("pea soup", 2);
        GroceryItem items4 = new GroceryItem("apples", 3);
        GroceryItem items5 = new GroceryItem("wheat bread", 2);
        GroceryItem items6 = new GroceryItem("tuna fish", 5);
        GroceryItem items7 = new GroceryItem("potatoes", 4);
        GroceryItem items8 = new GroceryItem("sourdough bread", 1);
        GroceryItem items9 = new GroceryItem("chedadar cheese", 1);
        GroceryItem items10 = new GroceryItem("green tea", 1);

        //creating groceryList called groceryList
        GroceryList groceryList = new GroceryList();
        
        //adding to the list
        
        groceryList.addItem(items1);
        groceryList.addItem(items2);
        groceryList.addItem(items3);
        groceryList.addItem(items4);
        groceryList.addItem(items5);
        groceryList.addItem(items6);
        
        groceryList.addItem(items7);
        groceryList.addItem(items8);
        groceryList.addItem(items9);
        groceryList.addItem(items10);
        
        
        //print current list
        //groceryList.printGroceryList(null);
        
        //sorting groceryList
        //groceryList.sortList();
        
        //change count of green tea to 2
        System.out.println(groceryList.getItem(9));
        
        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: *`"method where this needs to happen"`* - the method you've posted is empty. Did you have an **attempt**? Then **share** it, and explain what went wrong. If your goal is to gain knowable, then you should be interested in trying it out before asking a question.

Comment: The method was empty just to show the name and for easier identification while reading the rest of the code but seeing as this may cause confusion I will not do that next time. I did try it out various times independently **before** asking for help but I did not want to add my errors, as I though it would get flagged for it being too much, however keeping this in mind, the next time: to include errors and from the answers understand where I went wrong.

Comment: *"I did not want to add my errors"* - There would be only a few questions on StackOverflow if all folks were afraid of showing their errors and misconceptions. Mistake is a part of a process and every question on SO should demonstrate an **effort** - that's the rule. See [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*Open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: I see and understand! the _open letter to students with homework problems_, is actually very helpful. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public void changeItemCount(int k, int m){
   GroceryItem item = getItem(k); //just get the item from list
   item.setCount(m); //and change the count value
}
```

Comment: This should work and is a clean way of doing it imo


Note: Since it's a list of object, getting the object actually returns a reference to that object, so if you're changing the object you're getting, you'll also change the one in the list (since they are the same)
This wouldn't work if it was a list of int, or any primitive type

Comment: @SparklingMarcel is right, thank you for additional info ;-)